# JQueryt function returning undefined however alert is showing correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html page where i have UL and LI tags to create a menu. UL tag has class **category_menu** and LI's have id's 1,2,3, respectively. When someone clicks on this LI, I want to send that LI id as request parameter to Spring controller. Alert box is showing correct value but i am not getting correct value on browser console. its giving

```
../category.jsp?category=undefined
```

I am new to JQuery and JavaScript so can anyone tell me why that function is returning undefined although alert is showing correct value.

```
var payload = {
        "url" : "templates/category.jsp",
        "callback" : this.onLoadComplete,
        "data" : {
            'category' : function(){
                $('.category_menu li').click(function(){
                            alert(this.id);
                            return this.id;
                        });
            }
        },
        "context" : this
    };
};
```

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make any sense.  The payload should be constructed and sent inside the `click` handler, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in your code is that for data of category parameter you are defining a function and that function itself is doing nothing except for registering an event on click function of `.category_menu li`.

A quick fix can be following:

```
var globalvar = '';
$('.category_menu li').click(function(){
   globalvar = this.id;
});

var payload = {
    "url" : "templates/category.jsp",
    "callback" : this.onLoadComplete,
    "data" : {
        'category' : globalvar
    },
    "context" : this
 };
};
```

I haven't run the above code but i believe it'll provide you an idea what mistake you are doing and can resolve your issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var payload = {
    "url" : "templates/category.jsp",
    "callback" : this.onLoadComplete,
    "data" : {
        'category' : ""
    },
    "context" : this
};


$('.category_menu li').click(function(){
   payload.data.category=this.id;
});
```

And send this request it will be ok.